# Ubuntu 14.10 Intel Wireless 7260 - Bluetooth not working

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 14.10, iwlwifi, toshiba

I just installed the new wireless card, connected via Ethernet and Ubuntu recognized the new card, it recognized the card and installed the software and the WiFi on 2.4 and 5GHz started working perfect but there's no Bluetooth (No Bluetooth adapters found message). Everything is up to date.

I'm new to Ubuntu, learning a little every day but this issue is far away from my understanding. I'll appreciate any help.

Toshiba R835-P94

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[   22.144101] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X

[   22.314469] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.228.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm

[   22.370843] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, >REV=0x144

[   22.371011] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

[   22.377363] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

[   22.550928] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'

[   24.709629] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

[   24.710014] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

xx@xx-PORTEGE-R835:~$ ^C

xx@xx-PORTEGE-R835:~$ dmesg | grep iwl

[   22.144101] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X

[   22.314469] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.228.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm

[   22.370843] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144

[   22.371011] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

[   22.377363] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

[   22.550928] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'

[   24.709629] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled

[   24.710014] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:58e5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The bluetooth on an Intel 7260 usually shows in `lsusb` with ID of 8087:07dc

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the tip. I just added the details for lsusb

Comment: 10 months passed - did you found the solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi Alex, I haven't found a solution yet. It was absorbing too much of my time solving this issue. If you find the solution send me a message. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs help on enabling Intel 7260 Bluetooth under Linux. For the notebook version of the adapter, there are youtube videos about taping over the last pin, which seems to turn it on. I have the internal Pcie card, which requires that you hook up the USB cable (included with the adapter). The USB jack polarity is important, and can inadvertently be reversed, so check for that. My card was immediately recognized and Bluetooth works flawlessly once the cable was attached. That's on a Gigabyte AB350 Gaming 3 with Ryzen cpu and Kubuntu 18.04.